# C#: Unable to convert type A to type B where A = B

Tags: c#, types

I'm currently getting this error from an `InvalidCastException`

```
[A]System.Data.Objects.ObjectResult`1[EDMXAssembly.ServiceStatus] cannot be cast to 
[B]System.Data.Objects.ObjectResult`1[EDMXAssembly.ServiceStatus]. 
Type A originates from 'System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' in the context 'Default' at location 
'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.Entity\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.Entity.dll'. 
Type B originates from 'System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' in the 
context 'Default' at location 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.Entity\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.Entity.dll'.
```

Long and ugly!

I'm using reflection to invoke a method inside an assembly that is loaded at runtime. The method I'm invoking returns `ObjectResult<T>`. The error appears when I try to cast the result of the invocation to that.

I think this is due to the runtime loaded assmebly containing a reference to System.Data.Entity, as well as the assembly doing the reflection and casting; because these are two different references, the types are treated as not being the same. (How far out am I there?)

Is there any way around this issue? The method I'm invoking is on an `ObjectContext`, so I can't change what it returns.

Thanks

Edit for snippet:

```
public QueryResultSet<T> ObjectQuery<T>(string dataContext, string functionName, List<ObjectParameter> functionParameters)
{
    var context = htContexts[dataContext];
    ObjectResult<T> qResult = (ObjectResult<T>)context.GetType().InvokeMember(functionName, BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, context, functionParameters.ToArray());

    return qResult;
}
```

The error occurrs on the `qResult` line (I'm just mocking this really quickly up at the moment, hence lack of try-catch)

Comment: Show us a snippet of the code where you are invoking the method.

Comment: I'm pretty sure your analysis is correct; types from two different loads of an assembly are considered different types.

Comment: Have you tried using the var keyword and accessing the class properties? var foo = myClass.results();

Comment: @Jeremy: The invocation returns `object`, and then I need to cast to the right type. `var` will only allow me access to the standard `object` fields, won't it?

Comment: I think you are correct in your analysis and it's possible due to that the assemblies might be loaded into different load contexts (ie Load vs LoadFrom context). I would recommend to try Fusion Log Viewer to get enhanced assembly resolve information. Note that the culprit here could be: EDMXAssembly.ServiceStatus

Comment: Fusion Log Viewer (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4(v=VS.100).aspx)

Comment: I'm loading the assemblies at runtime using `Assembly.LoadFrom`. Could that be an issue in itself? `EDMXAssemvly.ServiceStatus` is the generic `T` I'm passing in the call.

Comment: Are there any telltale signs I should be looking for in Fusion Log Viewer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good example of why you need to keep interfaces in a common, separate library. You need to use an interface for `ObjectResult`. This way, your ObjectResult can have a common contract between your other assemblies.

**Edit**
If you are not able to apply any inheritance to the source `ObjectResult` you may have to perform more reflection over the object returned in order to *convert* it to your `ObjectResult`. Warning: this could be a costly conversion ...

...or refactoring to derive another solution.

Comment: How would I make an interface for `ObjectResult` in this instance? I'm not able to alter what `ObjectContext` returns. In theory, wouldn't `ObjectResult` would be a common contract between assemblies? but for there being two references to it here.

Comment: If you have an `ObjectResult` in one assembly, it is not equal to the `ObjectResult` in another assembly.

Comment: I've noticed. So there isn't really a way around this? Refactoring time, perhaps?